# Creating a Primary Key with multiple value (including Foreign Keys)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, composite-primary-key

I'am trying to create those tables using PostgreSQL:

```
create table OrgaoSuperior(
cod_superior int unique,
primary key(cod_superior),
nome_superior varchar(2000)
);

create table OrgaoSubordinado(
cod_superior int,
cod_subordinado int unique,
primary key(cod_superior,cod_subordinado),
foreign key(cod_superior) references OrgaoSuperior(cod_superior),
nome_subordinado varchar(2000)
);

create table Subfuncao(
cod_subfuncao int not null unique,
primary key(cod_subfuncao),
nome_subfuncao varchar(2000)
);

create table Acao(
cod_subordinado int not null,
cod_subfuncao int not null,
cod_acao int not null,
primary key(cod_subordinado,cod_subfuncao,cod_acao),
foreign key(cod_subordinado) references OrgaoSubordinado(cod_subordinado),
foreign key(cod_subfuncao) references Subfuncao(cod_subfuncao),
nome_acao varchar(2000)
);
```

But I'm getting SQL state 42830. I already tried using a UNIQUE constraint on cod_acao, but I don't want only cod_acao to be unique (it may repeat its values), I want the combination of cod_subordinado,cod_subfuncao and cod_acao to be unique (and to be the PRIMARY KEY of this table). Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: The Primary key does not accept duplicate value so Combination of `cod_subordinado,cod_subfuncao,cod_acao` this columns does not allow to duplicate

Comment: your sql works fine for me (postgres 9.3.4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Primary Key on only one column of a table and primary key is also not null and unique.

Comment: No, PKs can have multitple columns.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL state](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) 42830 has an alias of *invalid_foreign_key*.

> A [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.

But that seems to be the case in your tables.

Your code works with even [PostgreSQL 8.3.20](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/72016) - [9.3.1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/72016)

Comment: It says `cod_subordinado int unique` in the definition of `OrgaoSubordinado`, so `subordinado` alone does form a unique constraint. I would agree, however, that the OP seems to be confused about database design. Perhaps the issue is that the engine first of all detects that the column is part of the PK and disregards the `unique`?

Comment: @AndriyM i see, just missed that (i was looking at the `cod_superior` field, which has not got unique constraint).